# Listview in BottomSheetDialog not resize after keyboard show up

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

I have custom bottom sheet dialog layout where include header layout, `listview` and footer layout.

Here is the layout details

[image: Here is the layout details]

When the keyboard shown up, the footer layout that contain buttons resize, not the `listview`.

here is my `dialog_bottom_sheet.xml`

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/azure_dialog"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@color/azure_meta_dark"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/accent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bookmark_group_list_size"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_item_default"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_button_main"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/option_button_cancel"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_save"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_button_main"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/option_button_save"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want if the keyboard show up, the `listview` resize height not the buttons.

Comment: hi @Abhishek I already adding ScrollView to the top of parent and still didn't work as I expected. The dialog can be scroll but not going to top when keyboard come up. check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9KEQ.png
and i tried using `adjustPan` or `adjustResize` but not make any change

Comment: check my `xml` update

Answer (score 0):

**I made some small change in xml by setting width and height properties for your view and added layout weight for list view**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/azure_dialog"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@color/azure_meta_dark"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/accent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_item_default"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_button_main"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/option_button_cancel"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_save"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_button_main"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/option_button_save"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @FlamestX check the answer if it helps.